# Code refactoring, where to instantiate an object

Tags: python, oop, refactoring

I have two files, i.e `order.py` and `shop.py`. And I am instantiating a `Network` object in both of these files. i.e

`order.py`

```
from network import Network
...
network = Network()
```

`shop.py`

```
from network import Network
from order import Order
...
network = Network()
order = Order()
```

As you can see, I am importing from `order.py` in `shop.py`. Now if the `Network` class looks like the below code. Then it's called twice. and the message `Network object created` will be printed twice respectively.

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Network object created")
```

How to refactor this code, so that the `Network` object shouldn't called twice?
How would you refactor it? Should I make another file and instantiate the `Network` object there? i.e

`config.py`

```
form network import Network
network = Network()
```

and then import `config.py` in both `order.py` and `shop.py`?

Comment: This highly depends on why you need a network object inside order.py. But basically, there are two options that could work. Either create the object inside order.py and add a method to retrieve it. The other option would be to create the network in main and pass it through the constructor to order.py. If your network is kind of a global object I suggest you google for singleton. Another way would be to already create a network object inside network and import it from order and shop. I would not create another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import already instantiated object too, no need to instantiate again if it's going to be shared across modules.

**shop.py**

```py
form network import Network, network
.
.
.
```